# Buying cables and small electronics component offshore

Tags: cable

I am wondering whether anybody have experience with buying cables and small electronics off shore.

The site I have in mind is [alibaba.com](http://alibaba.com).  It is similar to ebay and the quotes I'm getting seem to be pretty good.  However, I'm a bit weary with dealing with offshore companies.

Looking to buy bulk order of network cables and USB cables.

Comment: Offshore of where?

Answer (score 3):

I tend to like [Monoprice.com](http://monoprice.com/).

Comment: the site looks good

Comment: I've had good experience with them thus far, and they come highly recommended to me by a number of people I trust.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried. got ripped off. there is no control of any sort.

They sell tons of fake name-brands there.

DO NOT SEND THEM ANY MONEY!!!

Comment: Good consumer advice ;) Your experience seems to mirror mine.

Answer (score 1):

to farseeker: at least you got something. I've send them money for what supposed to be smartphones and got nothing back (-4500$). Tried calling them - nobody would pick up and everything would go into some Chinese voicemail. There are no background checks from Alibaba itself. You 100 % better off buying cheap things from ebay! They have customer assurance program (meaning you get your money back if something is not as described or if you don't get anything in the mail).  Ha-ha - I even tried going to local police department - they just looked at me with sad faces and said there is nothing they can do.

5 years later - i'm still pissed...

and that was Alibaba's so called GOLD reseller.

P.s. Please - save yourself some money and don't buy stuff from Alibaba

Answer (score 0):

I've had bad, bad experiences with some offshore places like that, in particular TradeTang (no link on purpose).

I purchased what I thought were a whole bunch of 16gb USB Sticks at a fairly good price, and it turned out they were 512Mb USB sticks, and every time you hit the end of the disk it would start writing from the beginning again, destroying everything on there.

Obviously cables and whatnot are not so easy to fake, but even so, how much are you going to be saving? $50? Hardly seems worth it for the risk.

Also, I like to support my local economy, but that's just my personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

I think with any computer compenents the the maxim "buy cheap, pay twice". With things like USB cables and such it may not matter but you'll reget it if you use a prroly made cable with kills a mouse/keyboard/USB HDD.

With networking cables buying online is deafinately the way to go. High street and online price can very, in the UK there is a high-street company selling a 2m Blekin patch cable (not cross over) for £25. Online you could find this for 1/5 of the price, and for a non-belin you could find it cheaper too.

Its depends on your budget. Get some quites from local places, check out thigs like eBay, Amazon, and depending on location Best Buy/Maplins Electronics/Misco.